# lightbox pagseguro PHP

Tags: php

Preciso implementar o sistema de pagamentos do Pagseguro em meu site. Onde o usuário terá a opção de fazer pagamento único (Com 3 valores pré definidos ou estipular o valor) nesse caso os meios de pagamento seriam Cartão, Crédito e Débito e Boleto. Caso o usuário escolher Pagamento Mensal (Com 3 valores pré definidos ou estipular o valor) o pagamento seria recorrente apenas com cartão de crédito, gostaria de saber como fazer isso utilizando a lightbox.

Comment: Coloque o código de até onde conseguiu fazer e destaque a parte em que está com dificuldades.

Comment: Não comecei a fazer, estou lendo a documentação,mas não é muito clara (pelo menos para mim)

Comment: Bruno, te aconselho a utilizar o fancybox. É extremamente fácil trabalhar com ele. Quando você desenvolver o seu módulo de pagamento com o pagSeguro você vai realizar somente a chamada da sua página o resto o fancybox fará pra você. Segue link para os exemplos e download do fancybox: [https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)